# Archiving Courses in Google Clasroom Programmatically

Tags: .net, google-classroom

Is there any way to programmatically archive courses in Google Classroom through the API?

I have some sample code from Google on updating specific fields.
Could I just use this code and substitute whichever field indicates 'Archived' to this?

```
string courseId = "123456";
var course = new Course
{
    Section = "Period 3",
    Room = "302"
};

var request = service.Courses.Patch(course, courseId);
request.UpdateMask = "section,room";
course = request.Execute();
Console.WriteLine("Course '{0}' updated.\n", course.Name);

course = service.Courses.Update(course, courseId).Execute();
Console.WriteLine("Course '{0}' updated.\n", course.Name);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [**`update()`**](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/update) and update the **`courseStates`** to **`Archived`**. This will make the course to be archived. Note that you cannot modify it except to change it to a different state.

### Sample Request

Request parameters

id = 1234567890

Request body

```
{
  "courseState": "ARCHIVED",
  "name": "Test Course"
}
```

Hope this helps.